# How to cosign aggregate transactions involving a multisig

Tags: blockchain, nem

As a cosignatory, I am trying to sign an aggregate transaction where a multisig is involved. However, through the cosignatory partialAdded, I don't receive any transaction to cosign.

Example:

1. **Alice**, **Bob**, and **Charlie** are all cosigners on a **2 of 3** multisig account.
2. I am submitting an **aggregate bonded transaction** to remove **Alice**, and add **David**.
3. After the **lock** and **announce**, I see messages on `partialAdded` channels for **Bob** and **Charlie**’s accounts. However, querying **Bob** or **Charlie**’s accounts through the API shows 0 partials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From NEM Developer Center: [Signing announced aggregate bonded transactions¶](https://nemtech.github.io/guides/transaction/signing-announced-aggregate-bonded-transactions.html).

> To fetch aggregate bonded transactions that should be signed by
>   multisig cosignatories, refer to the multisig public key instead.

Aggregate transactions involving a multisig are not notified in the cosignatory partial channel. Not all of them require to be cosigned by all cosigners (only N out of M).

To cosign the transaction, you should **check the multisig partialAdded**, not the cosignatory account, and then announce the cosignature.

Comment: do you mean to use this api call ? `{{ base_url }}/account/{{ publicKey }}/transactions/partial` @dgarcia360

Comment: I am guessing to use this function [nem2-sdk](https://github.com/nemtech/nem2-sdk-typescript-javascript/blob/94ebe9e158d14b84720ed073a10f0a1300a558cd/src/infrastructure/Listener.ts#L253)